Laravel Sanctum for Chrome Extension User Authentication
I'm building a REST API backend in Laravel for a Google Chrome extension and need advice on how to approach authentication.
My research suggests using Sanctum, but all examples I’ve found focus on generating API tokens for developers. I haven't seen examples where Sanctum is used for mobile apps/chrome extensions where the token is all handled in the background without end-user involvement.
Is Sanctum a good option for my scenario? If so, what design pattern should I use for my case?
